# Background CLLocationManager stops updating after 15 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have set the info.plist with NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and the application runs in the background. Its just after about 15 minutes, it stops. Background mode and location services is enabled in the app capabilities section

Everything else seems to work perfectly fine.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"Entered Background");
self.appdelegatelocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.appdelegatelocationManager.delegate = self;
[self.appdelegatelocationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[self.appdelegatelocationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[self.appdelegatelocationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
[self.appdelegatelocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

Once i enter the app again and go into the background again it works again for another 15 minutes.

Please help!

Comment: For some odd reason, when i use the simulator, the app will run for hours on end. However, when i install it to my phone, it stops after about 15 minutes. I think my app might be getting suspended, but i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Settings > Target Under Background Modes enable the following files

1 - Location updates
2 - Background fetch.[image]

Link in the image.

Your problem will be solved.

Comment: I tried this, but it still stopped after about 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Did you move within these 15 minutes? If not, the `CLLocationManager` may stop to save energy. You can deactivate this via the property `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically`. The determination of the pause depends on the property `activityType` of the location manager.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620553-pauseslocationupdatesautomatical

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620567-activitytype